# Angular Material Slide Toggle not changing bound variable

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-directive

I have 2 strange problems. I have a large form with lots of input fields. That works fine. I want to add a slide toggle at the bottom which changes a variable that will affect styles on the whole form.

My first problem is that the variable will not display until the slide toggle is clicked.

HTML

```
<mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="ifPrint" name="ifPrint" id="ifPrint" ></mat-slide-toggle>

<div>
  {{ifPrint}}
</div>
```

COMPONENT

```
export class PrintReviewDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
ifPrint = true;
}
```

the ifPrint variable is blank on page load

The second problem is

when the slide toggle is clicked the div containing the variable shows as true but when I click the toggle to the off position the ifPrint variable stays as true and does not change.

I have created a [blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvpfu5-dsfytx) and it is working fine there with the same code so I am unsure as why I am having these issues on my page.

The console says:

```
Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'ifPrint'
```

EDIT: I updated the stackblitz to include the html of the form and now it is not working.

Comment: update your stackblitz with the `<form>` and some fields within the form... maybe there is some connection which is not reflected in the bare minimum SB

Comment: OK I will try that.

Comment: Stackblitz is not showing your result.Please update it

Comment: I have just updated the Stackblitz and now it is not working, the same as on my machine. So the problem has been reproduced. The toggle button at the bottom no longer works and the ifPrint variable does not show. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvpfu5-dsfytx

Comment: @PaulLeppard, check the answer below, you can extend that... let me know in case of any issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvpfu5-dsfytx) couldn't recreate the issue which you shared... But from your question, the following 2 issues are addressed for a form and styling is also done:

- the toggle value was not displayed by-default until the toggle was clicked
- the toggle value didn't change when you toggled it
- the style is now being updated based on the toggle value

relevant **TS**:

```
  model:any;
  constructor(){
    this.model = {name: '' , age: null, ifPrint: false};
  }
```

relevant **HTML**:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="formSubmit()" #demoForm="ngForm"  >
  <div [ngClass]="model.ifPrint === true ? 'trueClass' : 'falseClass'">
  <input type="text"  placeholder="Enter Name" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name" />
   <br/>
  <input type="number"  placeholder="Enter Age" #age="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.age" name="age" />  <br/>
  <mat-slide-toggle #ifPrint #age="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.ifPrint" name="ifPrint"></mat-slide-toggle> {{model.ifPrint}} <br/>
  </div>
<button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

check a minimal, [working demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvpfu5-4vp8hi?file=app%2Fslide-toggle-overview-example.html) for what you're trying... hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks Akber. This does prove that what i am trying to achieve can work. Me and my colleagues at work are stumped as to why it won't work when you copy the exact code into my app. I'm not sure what to do with it. If I create a new app it works. I need to keep looking for the reason.

Comment: Can you recreate the error/issue that you're getting on stackblitz?

Comment: No I can't unfortunately. It does not occur on StackBlitz. There must be something in my app configuration. Without uploading a lot of sensitive client info to a stackblitz I won't be able to replicate it. As your answer works and does what I intend to do I will accept it but I'm still stumped as to why it is not working in my app. I have found a workaround by using a click event to change the variable ifPrint so that will have to do for now. Too much work to do to spend any longer on this strange issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: My gut tells me to check the version of node packages - your code vs. stackblitz which works; I say that because it is working for your new project; also, I am curious to know if you changed any of the node packages of your app during the development phase ?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I removed everything in your template except the `mat-slide-toggle` and it works as expected.

I believe the issue is because your html template is referencing methods or properties that your component does not have, or trying to access a property of `null` or `undefined` somewhere is causing the issue.

Check your console for the errors and if you fix those up, the slide toggle should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for response but that is where I was at originally. I added the form to replicate the problem on my local machine. I will take out different sections of the form until It continues to work to narrow down the offending code.

Comment: I have been through the code and removed all undefined variables and the button works, so I believe you are correct in saying this is the source of the problem. I just have to go through the whole form to find them.

Comment: I have been through the whole code and removed all null values. I then removed all the code in the component except the material slider and I still get the error : Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'ifPrint'. My component is completely empty other than the mat slide toggle and I still get the error.